# Simulating critical values using standard Brownian motion

Tags: r, monte-carlo, brownian-motion, critical-value

Using `R`, I am replicating the Table 1 results of this paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610926.2014.985841. I wrote the following `r function` However, my output deviates significantly. Please see the equation below. I considered sample size `n  = 5` and generated from `rnorm(n, 0,1)`. Please see my `r codes` below. Could you please provide a hint to me? Thanks [image]

```
rm(list = ls())
cvalue = function(n, alpha) {
  rep = 1000  # number of repetitions
  stat = NULL
  for (i in 1:rep) {
    e1 = rnorm(n, 0, 1) # standard Brownian motion 1 
    e2 = rnorm(n, 0, 1) # standard Brownian motion 2 
    for(j in 1:n){
    t = j ;  s = j-1 # t <= s
    W1 =  cumsum(e1)[1:s] # Z(s)
    W2 =  cumsum(e2)[1:t] # Z(t)
    W12 = exp(-t) *  exp(-s)  # find exp(-t) * exp(-s)
    }
    stat = c(stat, max(W12*(W1- W2))) # line above eq (19) and get sup of that
  }
  critical = quantile(stat, 1 - alpha) # find the (1-alpha) quantile
  return(critical)
}

cvalue(5,0.05)
```

Comment: I am having difficulties ascertaining how your code implements anything in the foregoing equations.  Could you supply your explanations of what you think the code is doing, line by line?

Comment: @whuber I have added line-by-line descriptions.

Comment: Thank you.  But (1) why do you use the line preceding (19) rather than (19) itself; (2) where do you obtain the *double* suprema; and (3) why doesn't your computation of $Z$ agree with its formula in terms of $W$?

Comment: @whuber, first, I used the line preceding (19) which is easier to simulate. Second question, we always have `t >=s >=0`. Thus, I took the suprema only once. To answer the last question, `Z(t) = W(t)/e^{-t)`. I thought that `Z(t)` is the standard Wiener process. Therefore, I simply generated from the standard normal distribution. Is that correct?

Comment: @whuber, first, I used the line preceding (19) which is easier to simulate. Also, we can write in terms of `Z(t)`. That is , `sup sup e(-t)e(-s)(Z(s) - Z(t))`.

Comment: The line preceding (19) is algebraically identical to 19, just a bit more complicated.  Your second response looks circular, because what you call "Z" in the comments is represented by the variables `W1` and `W2`. This might be the crux of your problem.  How are you interpreting the expression "$W(e^{-t})/e^{-t}$"? The meaning is unclear because you haven't included the definitions or much context, but it would seem that "$W(e^{-t})$" is intended to be the value of a standard Brownian motion at "time" $e^{-t}.$